# Error en Genexus X Evolution 2 U6 con generador C# Win

Tags: genexus

Tengo un problema, en principio el sistema se estaba desarrollando en *Genexus 9*, después, se pasó a *Genexus x Evolution 2*, el generador *C# Win* se ejecutó y no hubo errores pero cuando queremos agregar una transacción, hacemos click en el botón agregar donde se llama la transacción desde el *Work Panel*. La transacción tiene la regla para donde pide que se pase el *ID* del `artículo(Tipo Numeric(6.0)`, `usuario(Tipo Varchar)`, `modo(Character)` y `tipo(tipo Numeric(1.0))`. La transacción se abre pero al mismo tiempo sale el siguiente error:

> Ocurrió una excepción no controlada en su aplicación. Si clickea en continuar, la aplicación ignorará este error e intentará continuar. Si clickea, la aplicación se cerrará inmediatamente.
>
> `Java. Lang.ClassCastException`: No se puede Convertir un objeto de tipo `System.Decimal` al tipo `java.Big.Decimal`.
>
> En `Genexus.Metadata.ClassLoader.ExecuteVoidRef(Object 0,String mthd, Object [] args)`.
>
> En `Genexus.ClassLoader.Execute(String assmly, string clss, Object [] constructor Args, string mthd, Object[]args)`.
>
> En `Genexus.Programs.uwsTrabajararticulos.E14VOB1()`.
>
> En `Genexus.Programs.uwsTrabajararticulosEventDispatch(Object eventSource)`.
>
> En `com.genexus.ui.GXWorkPanel.runEvent.run()`.

Answer (score 0):

En el generador Java existe una propiedad "USE JAVA ARITMETHIC DECIMAL"; por favor pruebe de poner esa propiedad en NO; luego vuelva a especificar forzado todo y verifique a ver si se soluciona.